# Starting Managed Server on Weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic12c

I am attempting to start a managed server on Weblogic 12c. I have followed the [documentation from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/NODEM/tutorial.htm#NODEM267) to do this, and every step works except for the last one. That is, I start an Admin server, and I start a Node manager successfully. But when I use Node manager to start a managed server, things go awry. In console, the state of my managed server says "FAILED_NOT_RESTARTABLE" and status of last action is "FAILED."

Here are the logs reporting the error:

`<Jul 21, 2016 2:51:42 PM EDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 12.2.1.0.0 Tue Oct  6 10:05:47 PDT 2015 1721936> 
<Jul 21, 2016 2:51:46 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<Jul 21, 2016 2:51:46 PM EDT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool.> 
<Jul 21, 2016 2:51:46 PM EDT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002942> <CMM memory level becomes 0. Setting standby thread pool size to 256.> 
<Jul 21, 2016 2:51:47 PM EDT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason: [Server:002653]The servers administration channel conflicts with the Administration Servers channel.> 
<Jul 21, 2016 2:51:47 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.> 
<Jul 21, 2016 2:51:47 PM EDT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down.>`

All the settings I used were default ones. The default port for the managed and Admin server is "9002". I've tried searching around, and changing one or the other of those values, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You should have enable the domain administration port which is 9002 by default. You can disable it or use another port for administration channel or use another port for your managed server

Comment: I tried to change the values for the administration ports so that the admin server's and the managed server's administration ports were the same, and then different. neither worked.

how do I enable or disable the administration port?

Comment: Using the admin console, select the domain, Configuration tab, General sub-tab and uncheck Administration Port Enabled

Comment: I checked that setting, and the "enable administration port" field was already unchecked.

Comment: You cannot have both servers on the same host using the same port. Use 7001 for administration server and 7101 for the managed server for instance